# Yii- How to add urlManager Rules within a module?

Tags: php, routes, yii, url-routing

In Yii framework, the main config file defines components.  one of which is urlManager:

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
                   'urlFormat'=>'path',
                   'showScriptName'=>false,
                   'rules'=>array('/'=>'site/homepage', //...
```

cool I like that, it works.  Now I'm creating a module and that module I want to have a some routing rules that are specific to the module.  I want /myModule/moduleController/action/:id to point to the action and pass an id along with it.  but I don't want to have to touch any files outside of the module.  I would think you could do this within the myModuleModule.php file.

I found a link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25801-url-rules-in-module-definition/ about one way to do it but it seems hacky, and not ideal.

**So my question: what is the best way to add urlManger rules within a module?**

Comment: The solution which you found is pretty good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is a weak point in Yii - Url management from within the module is not nicely implemented (or designed). I haven't read [this entire thread](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21884-module-and-url-management/) but it seems that this weak point hasn't escaped the attention of Yii's dev team and their thought/thinking about a solution. AFAIK, in the meantime, at the same breath when you load the module you'll need to plant the url manager rules in the config file.